# C# How to check if an object is a multi-dimensional array

Tags: c#, reflection

I am a newcomer to C#. I have an Object in C#, how to check if it is an single or multi-dimensional array?

```
int[,] array = new int[2,3];
object obj = (object) array;
if(obj is Array)
{
    if(obj.Rank==2) // I need to cast obj to array first in order to call Rank
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main ways to accomplish this. Either by [casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) `obj` to an `Array` as you suggested:

```
if(obj is Array && ((Array)obj).Rank == 2)
{
    //do something
}
```

Or using the [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):

```
var arr = obj as Array;
if(arr != null && arr.Rank == 2)
{
    //do something
}
```

Note that in both these solutions, I've combined the two `if`'s together using the [conditional AND operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) (`&&`) for simplicity. This will only evaluate this right hand side if the left hand side evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Thank you! Just realized that I can cast it to Array instead of int[] or int[,]