# Check if array have two elements

Tags: c#, arrays, xamarin.ios, azure-cognitive-services, face

I'm developing app in Xamarin.iOS to recognize faces on the photo.
I'm using Cognitive Services and Windows SDK. When I send photo with two faces (which corresponds to two different persons) I receive two elements array:

```
var result = results[0 or 1]
```

I wonder how I can check if array have two elements (because in most cases I send only 1 face, so result is have one element)?

edit
Maybe I will show my code:

```
var result1 = results[1].Candidates[0].PersonId;
var person = await fsc.GetPersonAsync(personGroupId, result);
Console.WriteLine($"Person indentified is {person.Name}");
```

`results[]` is an array where is returned faceID of recognized person. 
What I mean is that if I send photo with 2 faces I get return with `results[0]` and `results[1]` -> where are faceIDs of recognized persons. I would like to show to user that there are two persons on photo. But if I send photo with one face returned is array `results[0]`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `results[0 or 1]` syntax in C#. Can you go into a little more detail on that one?

Comment: Do you really mean 2D arrays, i.e., `[ , ]`, or are you rather talking about "jagged arrays" `[][]`?

Comment: Maybe it's duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642691/c-sharp-how-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: I think the question is how to determine whether the array length is 1 or 2

Comment: I don't think you really mean "two dimensional", but rather that it contains more than one element. That would be [`results.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In order to find out how many dimensions there are, use code such as the following.

```
Console.WriteLine(arr.Rank);
```

That returns the number of dimensions. I am not familiar with the `[0 or 1]` syntax you have used there.

Answer (score 2):

For a true two-dimensional array:

```
string[,] example1 = new string[3, 3] {{"a","b","c"},
                                       {"d","e","f"}, 
                                       {"g","h","i"} };
Console.WriteLine("Array has {0} dimensions, with {1} x {2} = {3} elements total",
                  example1.Rank,
                  example1.GetUpperBound(0) + 1,
                  example1.GetUpperBound(1) + 1,
                  example1.Length);
```

For a simple array with one or two elements:

```
string[] example2 = new string[]{"a","b"};

Console.WriteLine("Array has {0} elements.",
                  example2.Length);
```

For a jagged array:

```
string[][] example3 = new string[][]{{"a,b,c"},
                                     {"1","2","3","4"}};

Console.WriteLine("Array contains [0] arrays with [1] and [2] elements each",
                  example3.Length,
                  example3[0].Length,
                  example3[1].Length);
```

Comment: Ahh OK. I said it wrong. My array is not multi dimensional, it has 2 elements .

Comment: Glad I could clarify :)